# using cam in gotomeeting

Tags: nexus-7, nexus-4, webcam, gotomeeting

I have tried to use Nexus 7 for GoToMeeting appointment. I installed [app from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.citrixonline.android.gotomeeting), but I didn't have video during meeting. I could not find any button for web cam and didn't see any video in options. I tried Nexus 4 also with the same result.

I have again GoToMeeting appointment and don't know if can use camera. Anybody used GoToMeeting in Nexus? Maybe some options settings?

PS: I used video in skype on the same devices without problem.

Comment: I do not see any reference to that app in relation to camera usage on the Play Store?

Comment: you mean this app doesn't use camera at all? I used GoToMeeting on computer before and used web cam on it. People, who sent me GoToMeeting invitation want to see video, but I don't have web cam on computer now and used to use tablet or phone.

Comment: Read comment: "No Webcam Capability?! Mobile devices come standard with a front facing camera. How does this program come standard WITHOUT an option to enable your webcam to do video conferencing???

Comment: So, video is not available for this app?

Comment: Can anybody just confirm this?

Comment: Judging by the reviews and comments - it could well explain why there's no camera facility, perhaps write a  1-star review on the playstore explaining why and ask for ETA for a camera integration?